# NSOperationQueue Crash

Tags: ios, multithreading, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My app is crashing when invoking a completion block for an NSOperation subclass (AFURLConnectionOperation).  I'm not sure what this error message means:

NSOperation low-priority concurrency-limiting queue crash.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error message; it's a description of the thread your queue is on.  Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was reading the log wrong.  I was way off on the reason for this crash.  I was passing a message to a deallocated object.  The real cause of this crash was an unrecognized selector.